# Squares with squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are there a group of numbers whose squares are made up of squares? For example, $7$ would be one because $7^2$ is $49$ which has $2^2$ and $3^2$. $20$ would be another example.

What are these numbers called?

Please help me find good **tags** for this question.

Comment: I suspect such a number would be given a name; for the phenomenon is somewhat limited to 10-based representation of integers and hence may not be intrinsic.

Comment: no name that has stuck. 1681 works as 16,81. Well known

Comment: @willjagy Then I will name it! ;)

Comment: @TanMath-Name it **TanMath's** numbers.....:-)

Comment: A nice way would be to sit with the list of all square numbers and first filter out all such numbers whose first two digits (for 3 digits) are squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OEIS calls them [Numbers whose square is a nontrivial concatenation of other squares](http://oeis.org/A128783), and calls the sequence of their squares [Squares which are a decimal concatenation of two or more squares](http://oeis.org/A019547). One of the references from that latter sequence calls the squares [Smarandache square-partial-digital [numbers]](http://www.gallup.unm.edu/~smarandache/SYLSMITH.HTM).

Comment: These are numbers that can be partitioned into squares such as 49, 100, etc. But I am looking for 7, 10, etc. So technically it would not be the answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Updated.

Answer (score -3):

I am not agree with taking $20$ as a number of that kind ( or trivial in whose case $10, 30,40,50,60,70,80,90$ are too).

We show here that the only two-digit number with four-digit square of this kind is $41$. Looking at the algorithm of extraction of the square root in the figure below we can write

[image]

$$ab=x^2\Rightarrow 4\le x\le 9$$
$$y(20x+y)=cd=z^2\Rightarrow y(20x+y)\le 81\Rightarrow x=4$$

Hence $$y(80+y)\le81\Rightarrow y=1$$
No other possibility. In fact $41^2=1681$ as we wished.

Comment: What about 12, 13, etc.

Comment: $12^2=144;13^2=169$ these are not examples, sauf the 13 but with three-digit square and I wanted try with four-digit only. Thanks, I edit the lapse.

Comment: Then I am sorry to say that you have not fully answered my question...

Comment: Not only does this not answer the question, but it's not even clear what question it's attempting to answer. You appear to have your own idea of what numbers "*of that kind*" are, but you haven't defined it, and it's certainly not clear to me why you disqualify e.g. $38^2 = 1444 = 12^2 \times 10 + 2^2$

Comment: @Peter Taylor: you are right. Y have discarded myself one-digit squares in the square.